# Manipulating xcode schemes from the console

Tags: ios, xcode, console

In xcode, is it possible to create new schemes and/or to add files to an existing scheme from the command line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no officially supported way to create or manage Xcode projects from scripts, but you can use a community project to do that, for example CocoaPods' gem: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj